# Increasing GA daily request quota

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

We have a self-hosted content management system which offers clients the ability to sync data from their GA profile with the content they maintain within the application. So, we're dealing with an arbitrary number of clients who can have an arbitrary number of profiles. Each client is required to simply enter their profile ID and request a token.

The issue we are running into is our Google Developer project is hitting its 50k/day quota pretty quickly, but Google has been unresponsive with our requests to increase this quota. Does anyone have experience with requesting an increase? If so, about how long did it take?

Aside from a quota increase, does anyone have suggestions on how we can avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It can take several weeks to get the quota set up. That is why it is recommended that you keep a check on your quota and request when you hit 80% of max. Only way to avoid it is to tune your requests don't request data you already have again store it in your system. if its an existing customer you should only be requesting the last few days worth of data. Everything else is static and shouldn't change.

How long ago did you request it and how critical is your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your response DalmTo. We have submitted a couple of requests now, the latest being about a week ago. We do persist the data; however, it is mainly to compare the current and previous sync (which is daily). We're running about 8 requests per site per client. I can see that adding up very quickly. What is confusing is the developer console was showing upwards of 45-47k requests/day for the past week and a high ratio of client errors to successes; however, the past two days we've only been seeing 4-10k requests/day.

Comment: The developer console is very bad at showing you your quota.  I started keeping track of it on my own.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Unfortunately, since our application is self-hosted we are not able to easily do this. Is there any way to see more detailed request information from the project side of things?

Comment: nope,  I would love an API for this.  but there isn't one.  TBH you are lucky what you see now is 50% better then what we had a year ago.

Comment: I figured as much. It'd be a great console, but I feel like half of the sections don't even load. For instance, the project overview page just sits there and never loads.

Comment: IMO they have updated a lot of the cloud (compute engine , app engine) stuff but left those of us who just use the APIs hanging.   They have been updating it a lot lately we may just need to wait a little.

Comment: @DaImTo Sorry for asking here. Am I going to have to pay for everything over 50k requests? At this moment, the console asks to create a billing account.

Comment: It depends upon the API you are using.  You need to request a quota extension, some of the APIs require that you create a billing account to do that.  As far as i know the Google analytics api does not have any cost associated with an increased quota.   If there is one Google will let you know before they start charging you, and if they do charge you please let me know this should be documented..